# Move view only on textView not textField

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a viewcontroler with 2 textfields & 1 textview. I want to move the view up but only if the textview is selected not the textfields. With my current code the following is working like intended:

• view stays in place if you click on textfield
• view moves up if you click in textview before ever clicked on a textfield
• view moves down if click from textview to textfield

but

• view is not moving up if you click from textfield to textview

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

    var textview = true
        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
           textview = false
            view.frame.origin.y = 0

        }

        func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            textview = true
            **view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardRectAS.height + (view.frame.size.height - self.speichern.frame.size.height - self.speichern.frame.origin.y) - 10**
        }

    **var keyboardRectAS = CGRect()**
        @objc func keyboardWillChange (notification: Notification){

            guard let keyboardRect = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {
                return
            }
            **keyboardRectAS = keyboardRect**
            if notification.name ==  Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow || notification.name == Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame {

                    if self.textview == true {
                        view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardRect.height + (view.frame.size.height - self.speichern.frame.size.height - self.speichern.frame.origin.y) - 10

                        self.textview = false

                }



            }

            else {
                view.frame.origin.y = 0
            }

        }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        textfield1.delegate = self
        textfield2.delegate = self
        textview.delegate = self

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: Is `textFieldDidBeginEditing()` called when you switch from textview to textfield?

Comment: yes and `textViewDidBeginEditing()` the other way round

Comment: I solved it and added the missing codeline to the original post indicated by **  ** I took a global variable and assigned the keyboardRect to it